# Change UITableViewStyle & cells programmatically - Made in Storyboard, Mod in Code

Tags: ios, uitableview

A view controller class (subclass of UITableViewController) in this utility app is used to display 4 table views, 3 of which are entered via a navigation controller. In the storyboard, the style has been set to `UITableViewStyleGrouped`.
The question: Is it possible to programmatically change to `Style Plain` to use an index and free up some screen space to display the index? I have tried suggestions from other SO questions to modify this in the `init` and in the `viewDidLoad` without success.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.navigationItem.title = self.title;

   if ([[self parentViewController] isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {
      [self getNewDataForDate:nil];
      self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
   }
}
```

Edit 1: The real issue is beyond the above code. Changing the 'style' of a storyboard produced tableview with prototype cells (that are displayed there as grouped) must require some other mods to code. Is it here?

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListCell";
DetailTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

The result is this error:

```
Assertion failure in -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:]
```

Answer (score 1):

You set the table style when you initialize the table view (see initWithFrame:style:). You cannot modify the style thereafter. (this is from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html)).

Comment: It seems I am not modifying (initializing) the table view in code. And I can't find that method in the docs. Can you please lend a bit more light?

Comment: You are using the method yourself: 
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

Comment: Ok, I meant that line to be `Plain` and now (edited above) it's throwing an assertion failure with `-[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:]`. Could that be the Dynamic table, with prototype cells that are set to grouped? With a breakpoint, the tableview is of type: Plain.

Comment: Looking into it, the program steps completely through `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to return cell, on the first cell of the first section and then throws the exception. Does the cell need to be built programmatically also?